# Two people who are allied or friends, yet are against each other

Tags: word-request, british-english

I need as many words as possible, if any exist, for:

> Two people who are allied or friends, yet are against each other.

I apologise if this sounds stupid but I couldn't find anything similar elsewhere.

Comment: Could you provide a context? how come friends or allies are against each other?

Comment: I think she means to say people who are friends to each other in pretense.

Comment: He means* for example let's say america and england could be ***** when they're at war to see who can provide the best service for their countries.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would include the substance of that comment in your question, so readers may immediately see what you mean. You may do so by clicking on the **edit** link immediately below your question.

Answer (score 9):

Rather than using a word to describe the parties concerned, people might speak of a *friendly rivalry* between the two.

Answer (score 0):

*[Frenemy](http://frenemy.urbanup.com/2424107)* is maybe the word you are looking for. Even though it's more a colloquial way to mean *two people who are allied or friends, yet are against each other* rather than a word you would find in a proper dictionary.

Comment: Not enough rep to vote down here yet but I strongly disagree-- not a common word or generally accepted usage; should not be given to learners.

Comment: Actually, frenemy was recognized by Merriam Webster as a new edition to the dictionary a few years ago. That is the beauty of language, it is dynamic.

Comment: The NOAD reports _frenemy_ as word.

Comment: Not everything listed in the NOAD is widely accepted usage. In a bid to increase its popularity, the NOAD has started eagerly adopting passing slang. [Speak English? You've Got Some New Words!](http://94wysp.radio.com/2010/08/24/speak-english-youve-got-some-new-words/)

Comment: The problem is that it is very easy for English speakers to spontaneously come up with portmanteaux like *frenemy* and to understand such. Can you imagine if dictionaries start listing every possible portmanteau? Let me make up a few words on the spot. *negositive*: a kind of negative positive! *nerdiot*: smart, but cannot see the forest for the trees. *soliquid*: not solid, not liquid. *cheapensive*: discounted expensive thing. These are not genuine words, but easily understood word mash-ups that anyone can come up with. It's a linguistic process that can quickly fill dictionaries with junk.

Comment: See also http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frenemy

Comment: Actually frenemy means the opposite of what the OP wants, I think.  They're looking for friends who are put up against each other, but a frenemy is someone who just pretends to be a friend but is really an enemy.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively recent term to describe two rivals who are yet friends is [frenemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenemy).